React Native: Background does not cover the entire screen of IOS devices
I am currently playing around with react native for an upcoming project, using expo as the framework. I cannot get the background to expand to fill the whole screen of my IOS device (Iphone 13). As seen in the image, there is white space on the top and bottom of the screen, but I am not using SafeAreaView, is there a way to fix this?
How the app looks like on Iphone 13
How I want it to look like
Looking at online tutorials, I see that using SafeAreaView is what causes this, but I am currently not using it.
Below is the code used in index.tsx (this is apparently the home file unlike App.js for some I have seen)
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, ScrollView} from "react-native";

export default function Index() {
  let name = "User";
  function handlePress() {
    console.log("I'm pressed");
  }
  return (
    <View style = {styles.open}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
            Hello {name}</Text>
        <Button title = "Click Me!!" onPress={handlePress} color='midnightblue'/>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
  open: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
  },
  container: {
    padding: 30,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
    height: 200,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  paragraph: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    fontSize: 42,
  },
})


You have used SafeAreaView in your app that is not taking up full height. Check that. There is no other reason for this error.
